# Confusion on the Finkelstein reaction(AKA halogen exhange reaction)

Tags: organic-chemistry, solvents, nucleophilic-substitution

So in the Finkelstein reaction, the iodide ion is supposed to replace another halogen(say chlorine) through SN2 mechanism.
But here, Acetone is used, which is a polar aprotic solvent. And in acetone, iodide ion is the weakest nucleophile. So how can it replace the chlorine?

Aren't we better off if we use water or ethanol(which are polar protic solvents) since (I-)
acts as the strongest nucleophile?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68081/why-isnt-a-polar-protic-solvent-used-in-the-finkelstein-reaction ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/133984/why-is-finkelstein-reaction-not-conducted-using-naf ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/55304/role-of-acetone-in-the-finkelstein-reaction .. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6947/why-are-nacl-and-nabr-not-soluble-whereas-nai-is-soluble-in-acetone-in-the-fin

Comment: the driving force of Finkelstein is the insolubility of the product halogen salt (KCl for ex) so that it is removed from the reaction.

Comment: Iodide would be also be a worse nucleophile in a protic solvent.